# Using slash character in url route

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to define a url in Laravel 4.1 which contains slash character. But I can't do that in Laravel 4.

This is my code:

```
<?php

// app/routes.php    

Route::get('my/car', function()
{
    return 'This is car page';
});
```

Comment: whats the error? it should work

Comment: Error is "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.". Notice that, I am using xampp with windows OS.

Comment: So turn on $debug=true in config/app.php and see what the error actually is.

Comment: Ok, "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException" exception occurs.

Comment: And does any route work in your project? Or is this your first route? i.e. what if you change it to Route::get('my', function()...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, another routes works fine like 'hello' and so on. :\

Comment: One last question - do you have Route::get('my/...') - with anything else? Maybe post your full routes file

Comment: @TheShiftExchange, No. now my rotes.php just contains 'my/car' route and It don't works.

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri Post the full exception message.

Comment: (o_O) very wonderful!!! now It works without changing anything.

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri How come?

Comment: Just I enable debugging in config/app.php and then disable it!!! I can't reproduce this bug again. So, I do not know why this exception was occured?! (o_O)

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri This may not a bug.